# Blocking POST/GET Method in a Web application

Tags: jakarta-ee, war, application-server

How to block POST/GET Method in a Web application deployed in application server.

so that http status code 405 [Method Not Allowed] will be thrown when it access via a blocked method.

**Description for HTTP Status code [405] :**
    A request was made of a resource using a request method not supported by that resource;[2] for example, using GET on a form which requires data to be presented via POST, or using PUT on a read-only resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by blocking you mean not accepting any incoming `GET / POST` requests, you have two solutions:

1. Define a `Filter` that will block the requests
2. Do it at the web server level

In the filter, you could do for instance:

```
public void  doFilter(ServletRequest request, 
                      ServletResponse response, 
                      FilterChain chain)
    ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendError(405,
                                "the error message" );                          
}
```